# memory leak in nonpaged "file" tag

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, memory-leak

I have a Windows 2012 R2 std. server with a memory leak. Something tells me that the leak started after we installed Symantic Endpoint protection 12.1.5 - but I am not sure. I tried to disable Symantic without any change to the memory leak.

Using RamMap I can see that The Nonpaged Pool grows ~1GB per day. 
Using Poolmon, I can see that the “file” tag is the cause of the memory leak in the nonpaged pool.

How do I debug this further? I seems like “file” is a generic tag used for unknown files? Or I cant really search for that?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated..

**Update:**

[image: Update: Memory Leak]

[image: Memory Leak 2]

Comment: Ouch... that really is the least helpful pool tag ever.

Answer (score 1):

Use XPerf/Windows Performance Analyzer to record pool allocations.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2012/11/30/troubleshooting-pool-leaks-part-7-windows-performance-toolkit.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I am downloading XPerf/Windows Performance Analyzer right now. I hope that it can help me locate the sinner.

Comment: Ok, I got a little further now.  I captured a dump of the file tag, and I can see that the process csrss.exe is causing the leak. For some reason I can’t load symbols in Windows Performance Analyzer, so I can’t get more information about what is causing this . (I can see that other people have the same problem, but unfortunately it don’t help to copy the .dlls manually like suggested here https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/xperf-symbol-loading-pitfalls/).

Comment: @user2536967 if you use Windows Server 2012 R2, you have to use the Windows 8.1 SDK/WPT, not an older version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891

Comment: @user2536967 does the new WPT work? Do you see stacks in the new captured ETL file?

Comment: no, I already used the newest version. I tried to install on my Windows 7 as well with same result.

Comment: It worked after reinstall - thanks for all the help...  Is it a valid conclusion that libwsa.dll is the cause of the leak (see screenshot in main text)? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, by looking closer it actually looks like it has something to do with remote desktop  :/

Comment: load the debug symbols to so that we can see the function names.

Answer (score 0):

Use perfmon to track which process has run-away pool allocations.  I don't have a server to hand, but the counters are something like "process\memory\pool nonpaged" and "process\memory\paged".

Also, what is the role of the server?  Do you have volume shadow copies enabled?

Comment: It’s a combined SQL 2014 and SCADA server (Proficy iFIX) We don’t have any disk configured for Volume Shadow Copies.

Comment: Cool - thanks.  Be interested to hear which process has growing NPP allocations... should be easy to spot if your pool is growing this fast.  I am surprised you're not seeing kernel lock-ups.

Comment: I have actually already tried to run “Process\Memory\Pool Nonpages(*)” overnight, and none of the services  looked suspicious (increased in size) even though the total size increased (I can upload csv if you are interested).